# Dynamically Display HTML Table columns from an Array

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular page that returns the following data through an Array

```
["BO01", "BO03", "BO04", "C.A.1.", "C.F.1.", "C.F.4.", "C.L.1.", "C.M.4.", "C.R.1.", "C.R.3.",…]
```

What I am trying to do is, display,  these Array values in  an HTML column

```
<tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax">BO01</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">BO03</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">BO04</th>
  </tr>
```

Comment: How have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-repeat to iterate through your array and display columns

js

```
$scope.columns = ["BO01", "BO03", "BO04", "C.A.1.", "C.F.1.", "C.F.4.", "C.L.1.", "C.M.4.", "C.R.1.", "C.R.3."];
```

html

```
<tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax" ng-repeat="col in columns">{{col}}</th>
</tr>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/W58s17FROUpokn77k07g)**